# 2 PWA but only 1 installed

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend, progressive-web-apps

I have a pwa react app, inside i can click in the button and open another APP. For example [www.pog.dev.lol.com](http://www.pog.dev.lol.com) and [www.pog2.dev.lol.com](http://www.pog2.dev.lol.com). The problem is when i add to home screen The first APP, it opens in full screen when i click and it redirects to The second one, is not anymore unless it os also added to home screen.

But i want to have only One installed, and The others that Will be redirects by this, Will be also fullscreen and pwa without installing.